# Is there any SQL query character limit while executing it by using the JDBC driver

Tags: sql, jdbc

We are using a query with IN clause to filter resultset on the basis of a parameter value. In that parameter, we have more than 10K values. Is there any character limit in SQL query while executing it with JDBC statement.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN IN (value_List)
```

where value_List have more than 10k comma separated values.

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
String sql ="SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMNNAME IN (value_List)";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [SQL TOP, LIMIT or ROWNUM Clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sqL/sql_top.asp)

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras the `sql` tag is about valid ANSI/ISO SQL standards.. Those limiting keywords arn't valid ANSI/ISO SQL but SQL dialects invented by database vendors.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) .. *"Is there any character limit in SQL query"* Also most likely you would also have to tag a database product like MySQL, PostgreSQL or SQL Server as string handling is not really (totally) defined in the SQL standards.